Font going to wrong path with expo on xcode simulator
So, i have a expo react native app and i have opened it in xcode and im running it in the simulator with no problems other than the fonts are not loading. i have my fonts stored in assets/fonts in my react native root folder and in the generated ios folder theyre in assets/assets/fonts. So when its in the simulator the fonts get placed in .app so in the root folder causing them not to be loaded since my code expects them to be in .app/assets/assets/fonts, how would i fix that all help is appreciated.
Error
Where the fonts are stored when its loaded in the simulator
App.json

{

  "expo": {

"assetBundlePatterns": [

        "**/*"

    ],

    "fonts":{

        "GothamRoundedMedium":"./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_medium.otf",

        "GothamRoundedBold":"./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_bold.otf",

        "GothamRoundedLight":"./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_light.otf",

        "GothamRoundedBook":"./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_book.otf",

        "GothamNarrowMedium":"./assets/fonts/gotham_narrow/GothamNarrow-Medium.otf",

        "GothamNarrowXMedium":"./assets/fonts/gotham_narrow/GothamXNarrow-Medium.otf"

      },

    "name": "main",

    "displayName": "appname",

    "entryPoint": "./index.tsx",

    "slug": "appname",

    "version": "1.0.0",

    "orientation": "portrait",

    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",

    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",

    "splash": {

      "image": "./assets/splash.png",

      "resizeMode": "contain",

      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"

    },

    "ios": {

      "supportsTablet": true,

       "bundleIdentifier": "com.anon.hsl",

      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"

    },

    "android": {

      "adaptiveIcon": {

        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",

        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"

      },

      "package": "com.anonymous.hsl"

    },

    "web": {

      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"

    }

  }

}

Metro config file

// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro

const { getDefaultConfig: getDefaultExpoConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const { mergeConfig, getDefaultConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

 

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */

const expoConfig = getDefaultExpoConfig(__dirname);

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

 

const { assetExts, sourceExts } = expoConfig.resolver;

 

const config = {

    transformer: {

        ...expoConfig.transformer,

        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer/expo")

    },

    resolver: {

        ...expoConfig.resolver,

        assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),

        sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]

    }

};

 

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, expoConfig, config);


How im loading the fonts
const load_fonts = async() => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'GothamRoundedMedium': require('./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_medium.otf'),
    'GothamRoundedBold': require('./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_bold.otf'),
    'GothamRoundedLight': require('./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_light.otf'),
    'GothamRoundedBook': require('./assets/fonts/gothamrnd_book.otf'),
    'GothamNarrowMedium': require('./assets/fonts/gotham_narrow/GothamNarrow-Medium.otf'),
    'GothamNarrowXMedium': require('./assets/fonts/gotham_narrow/GothamXNarrow-Medium.otf'),
  });

};

I tried changing the path of the fonts in the way im loading the fonts to match how it would be in the simulator but i couldnt since it wouldnt match my react native folder structure

It seems like its only an issue in the Xcode simulator, when i make a .ipa build everything seems to work fine
